# Run a property-test's iterations in parallel?

Tags: haskell, property-based-testing, haskell-hedgehog

I have a property-based test (in Hedgehog), that does the following:

- Push an item to a remote service that queues it
- Poll the remote service to figure out when the item was processed
- Assert some properties on the item's processing results

The test is running very slow because the 100 iterations are run sequentially. Is there any way to parallelize this? [checkParallel](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-15.6/hedgehog-1.0.2/Hedgehog.html#v:checkParallel) sounds like it runs multiple *property-tests* in parallel, whereas I want multiple *iterations* of the *same test* to be run in parallel?